# Undetermined coefficients with tricky particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How could I solve the diff eq

$$y''-7y'+4y=2x^3+xcosx+e^x+x^3e^{5x}$$

If undetermined coefficients were to be used, how could I set it up?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that if $y_1$ is a particular solution to $y''-2y'+y = g_1$ and $y_2$ is a particular solution to $y''-2y'+y = g_1$, then $y_1 + y_2$ is a particular solution to $$y''-2y'+y = g_1 + g_2.$$

So I would break this problem up and find the particular solutions to each of the four terms on the RHS of your original equation. E.g., to find the particular solution to

$$y''-2y'+y = 2x^3$$
use an Ansatz of $y(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D$.

Comment: Well, use the same principle. The general expression will be a long linear combination for each of the terms on the right.

Comment: I'm lost........ could you please show me?

Comment: Do you understand why we use the form $y(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D$ for the equation $y''-2y'+y = 2x^3$?

Comment: Not exactly, could you explain that ?

Comment: You need to go back to simple problems first. This problem is designed to build on the simple problems. I can't teach you the entire method here from scratch I'm afraid. You might find this helpful:
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/second-order-differential-equations/undetermined-coefficients/v/undetermined-coefficients-1

Comment: what would be the particular solution for xcosx? I got the others, but not that one

Comment: What kind of terms do you get when you differentiate $x\cos x$? You get linear combinations of itself together with $x\sin x$, $\cos x$ and $\sin x$.

Comment: (Ax+B)cosx+(Cx+D)sinx? does that look right?

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing.

Comment: then I can just add all of the particular solutions together and get the full particular solution .... lots of constants!